# Problem with binary ==

Tags: c++

I've run into strange problem with binary `operator==`.
I have a function which returns:
`Type< Colors >* get();`, `T` is of type `enum Colors {Red,Black}`
and I have an `operator==` defined as:

```
bool operator==(Type<Colors>* left, Colors right)
{
//...
}
```

Now, in code I have line:

```
if (get() == Red)
{
//
}
```

but here I'm getting error saying that:

```
error C2679: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Colors' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          could be 'built-in C++ operator==(Node<Key_T,Value_T> *, Node<Key_T,Value_T> *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Key_T=int,
1>              Value_T=int
1>          ]

or       'bool operator ==(const Type<T> *,const Colors)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Colors
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(Node<Key_T,Value_T> *, Colors)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Key_T=int,
1>              Value_T=int
1>          ]
```

Obviously the second match is what I've intended to use and it's perfect match yet it doesn't want to ;) compile. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message you posted says your `get()` function doesn't return `const Type<Colors>*` but rather `Node<Key_T,Value_T>*`. Are you calling `get()` on the appropriate object?

Comment: @Pablo it looks to me like I do.

Comment: what is the definition of get?

Comment: Could it be just the difference in `cost`ness? That's the only thing I see.

Comment: look at the error: it looks to the compiler that `get()` returns `Node<int,int>`!

Comment: you should give some more details about your `get()` function. From the error message it seems the return type of `get()` function has some problems or may be your `class Colors` doesn't have a proper `operator==`, but this is just a guess.

Comment: What is 'Red'  in your code declared as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is more diagnostic than an answer per se... but too much for a comment.)

Works ok for me with GGC 4.5.2:

```
enum Colour { Red, Black };

template <typename T>
struct Type { };

bool operator==(Type<Colour>*, Colour) { return true; }

int main()
{
    Type<Colour>* p;
    return p == Black;
}
```

Please try the above on your compiler and post the error message if any.  If none, please post your EXACT complete program as the error is likely some subtle thing you haven't posted.

Comment: GCC 4.5.2 and `operator ==()` return value

Comment: @iammilind: fair point - I originally only declared the operator to prove it'd get a link error, then decided to whack a body on so I'd prove it completely compiled and linked... it continues to do so with a "return true;" thrown in (edited in now too).

Answer (score 0):

The function `operator==` neither modify left or right ?

So put then const and it will works.

Comment: Wrong, the arguments are passed by value. No `const` needed.

Comment: As presented, it's a non-member function, so there's no object in respect of which the function can be `const`.  Konrad's covered the possibility that you meant the function parameters themselves.

Comment: If the first argument is of type const Type<Colors>* it won't compile even if the function don't modify the pointer value. That's why he should put const where he can.